# How can I retrieve data from an XSLT table up to the EOP tag?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file that contains several paragraph tags
Each paragraph has different types of tags that are under the content tag
The file contains an EOP tag in various places and I use a function to divide into a separate DIV for each problem page that EOP is sometimes found Inside an internal tag in the attached example, inside the table tag and when retrieving all the data in the table is received including after the EOP tag, how can the data in the table be retrieved only up to the EOP tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <statement>
    <mainBody>
      <paragraph>
       </paragraph>
          <eop/>    <paragraph>
        <content>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <p>p</p>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>a</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <eop/>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>b</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </content>
    </paragraph>
    </mainBody>
  </statement>
</root>



<xsl:template match="statement">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop" >
      <div class="page" id="div_{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::paragraph]" />
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::node()" group-starting-with="eop">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::content/table]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content/table">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

how can the data in the table be retrieved only up to the EOP tag?

Comment: Please do NOT post the same question twice!